# Asterisk ${CALLERID(name)

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I am working with asterisk (Asterisk 1.8.11.0), freepbx (2.x) and was building a dialplan (`extension_custom.conf`).

I wanted to get caller Name from database which i have stored for example.

```
CLI> database show cidname
/cidname/XXXXXXXXXX                             : Tikejhya
```

And i am able to get caller number, and also caller name but static way.
[I am well aware that freepbx supports phonebook but my requirement is to get that before it hits context]

; This gives you Number of Caller
exten=> _.,n,Log(NOTICE, "Incoming CallerID Number: ${CALLERID(num)}")

```
; This gives you Name of Caller
exten=> _.,n,Log(NOTICE, "Caller name:                  ${DB(cidname/XXXXXXXXXXX)}")`

And now my goal was to get that Caller name using 
`exten=> _.,n,Set(CALLERID(name)=${DB(cidname/${CALLERID(num)})})
```

However this seems not to provide value that i would expect to get which is `XXXXXXXXXXX`

Am i doing anything wrong.
(I am trying to do this because i need it before going to relevent context.)

Comment: Please check output of : Noop(--${CALLERID(num)}---). Probably you will see your answer